# Plug custom unit tests into Visual Studio's Test Explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd

I'm looking at ways to make our homegrown unit testing framework interoperate with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013's Test Explorer window.

[Our unit testing framework](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/tree/master/src/appleseed/foundation/utility/test) is simple but it suits our needs perfectly. It was developed long before Google Test or Visual Studio C++ unit testing framework were released. We have thousands of unit tests written with it, and we are not willing to rewrite them at this point.

However, since Visual Studio can now discover and run unmanaged C++ unit tests from within the IDE, it would be nice to exploit this feature, *without switching to Visual Studio's native unit testing framework*.

I suspect that it should be possible to make our unit tests discoverable by Test Explorer by placing them in the right C++ namespace and by DLL-exporting them.

Has anyone done this, and if so, how?

Edit: sample unit tests with our framework:
https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/blob/master/src/appleseed/foundation/meta/tests/test_cdf.cpp

Comment: This question is more suitable for msdn social

Comment: Right; MSDN question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ecdcbff-4c1b-43c0-8988-6071255a4f7e/plug-custom-unit-tests-into-visual-studios-test-explorer?forum=vcgeneral